# Android Studio app lags on certain devices

Tags: android

I recently posted an arcade game on the Google Play Store. After reviewing it and considering the final version good enough to be played, I posted it.

I ran the app on some Android phones and it didn't seem to be laggy or anything. However, my friends back home, in Europe, seem to experience lags making the game sometimes hardly playable.

Any idea what could cause such an issue?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are too many low performing devices on the market. You can get a device with 2 core 1GHz Mediatek CPU, for example, to check how your app performs on low-end devices.

Also, if your app depends much on network communications, people who are far from your servers can experience lags as well.

Comment: Thanks, it is kind of a shame. If my app doesn't use any network connectivity, is there a way I can make my app not lag on those devices? Any way to diminish the CPU use of my app?

Comment: You can try to profile it in Android Studio, find the parts of the code loading CPU the most and optimising them

Comment: CPU is one issue, memory is an additional. If you have little RAM, that can also cause problems

Comment: How would you "profile it in Android Studio"? Also, how do you optimise those parts? Do you try to make them more compact, delete irrelevant code...?

Comment: To profile, you can start with Android Monitor: open Monitors tab in lower area of Android Studio's window: https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/am-basics.html To optimise you need to perform fewer CPU-intensive / memory-intensive / network-intensive operations in the slow part of the code.